# What is the book/novel Mike Ross refers to in the pilot of Suits?

Tags: reference, props, suits

In the pilot of Suits, in the scene during the hotel interview with Harvey,

> Harvey asked how Mike knew they were cops.  Mike said he read a novel when he was a kid that helped identify the hotel worker and other patron were cops.  Mike also said he asked them for the time to throw them off because who would ask a cop for the time with a suitcase full of pot.

Is this book he's referring to real or something made up to help the plot of the pilot episode?  If the book IS real, can someone tell me what the title/author is because I'm curious to read it too.

UPDATE: I think my question is part of the plot of this episode and of the series because if he didn't read that novel as a kid, didn't have photographic memory to remember the details of the book, wasn't super smart and observant with what he read in the book and noticing the sign regarding the swimming pool being closed, he would have walked into the sting operation in the hotel room and got arrested, never accidentally making it to the interview with Harvey, and we wouldn't have a show to watch for 9 seasons.

Comment: Your update still doesn't give a reason for the importance of knowing whether or not it's a real book, and, if it is real, which book it is, right?